# Reichardt's equation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Just now I found an example violating Hasse Minkowski theorem. Which is $X^4-17=2Y^2$. But in order to show it has solution in $Q_p$ its written that reduction of the curve has genus $1$ for ail $p$ except for $p = 2$ and $p = 17$.

Could anyone please elaborate why is that ? and how to actually compute genus here ?